# debugging in R Studio. How to set editor breakpoint

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio, breakpoints

I'm new to R (R Studio) and I'm trying to figure out how the debugger works.
When i set an editor breakpoint in the middle of the code, R completely ignores it and executes the whole thing.

How do I for example set a breakpoint in the middle of this for loop to debug?

```
seed <- 1337
set.seed(seed)

nn    <- c(10,50,100,500,1000)
E_hat <- matrix(0,length(nn),1)
E     <- matrix(0,length(nn),1)

for (i in 1:length(nn)) {

        N     <- nn[i]
        mu    <- 0
        sigma <- 1

        # The phi function we want to integrate
        phi <- function(u) {exp(u)}

        # Draw random uniform numbers
        uni <- matrix(runif(N),N,1)

        # Convert to Gaussian PDF
        u <- mu + sigma*qnorm(uni,mu,sigma)

        # Take arithmetic average over the phi function
        E_hat[i] <- 1/N * sum(phi(u))

        # Analytical mean of log-normal distribution
        E[i] <- exp(mu+sigma^2/2)

        print(sprintf("-----------------------------------)"))
        print(sprintf("Results with N = %.4f", N))
        print(sprintf("Simulated mean %.4f", E_hat[i]))
        print(sprintf("Analytical mean %.4f", E[i]))
        print(sprintf("Difference %.4f", E_hat[i]-E[i]))
        print(sprintf("-----------------------------------)"))

}
```

Comment: Click to the left of the line number where you want to set the breakpoint. For more advanced troubleshooting [see here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534337-Breakpoint-Troubleshooting).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have already read the tutorial. Problem is that when I click to the left, highlight all my code and press ctrl+a and ctrl+shift+enter the code doesn't stop, but executes the whole thing without entering debug mode.

Comment: I don't think debug mode is made to work with Ctrl+Enter or Ctrl+Shift+Enter runs, it works when you source the file. Click the "Source on Save" box and save your code (or just `source` the file).

Comment: And, if you don't like the RStudio behavior (as described), you can put `browser()` in your code where you want the breakpoint to be. That will work however you run the code.

Comment: Hi Gregor. Thanks for your answer. The browser() function did what i wanted to. I'm used to Matlab where the breakpoint stops the code no matter how you run it - just like the browser() does. Guess debugging in R is just a pain in the ass compared to matlab, VBA etc.?!